# C++, wxWidgets, TDM-GCC compiler: undefined reference to WinMain in drive H:\?

Tags: c++, gcc, wxwidgets, winmain

**Not an undefined reference** to WinMain@16

I'm using Code::Blocks 13.12 with TDM64 MinGW compiler.
I'm trying to compile a basic wxWidgets program here, copied and pasted with the correct header and .cpp files names: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Adding_A_Control

```
g:\progr\tdm-gcc\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\..\lib\libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o) 

In function `main':

    h:\crossdev\src\mingw-w64-v3-svn\mingw-w64-crt\crt\crt0_c.c
    undefined reference to `WinMain'
```

I have TDM installed on a flash drive in G:. Is this an error about H:\ being a non-compiled version of C:\ or so?

Comment: Evading a question ban by completely repurposing an older question is _not_ okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have forgotten to use `wxIMPLEMENT_APP()` in your program code.

Comment: The other problem I get is that I get:  undefined reference to `TextFrame::TextFrame(wchar_t const*, int, int, int, int), TextFrame being the class derived from wxFrame.

Comment: You must have also forgotten to implement this ctor.